# How to compare value of int number[1] with number[2] c++

Tags: c++, numbers

I need to create a program that will accept 5 inputs and then i should show the highest value of the 5 inputs. But there is a problem, i need to compare the value of `number[0]` with `number[1]` in order to get the highest number available. And also, I need to make sure that if the user enters the same number as before it shouldn't be accepted and will tell the user to input another number.  Here's what I came up to...

```
int i,number[5],highest,max = number[i] + 1;    
int main(){
clrscr();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"\nEnter number :";
    cin>>number[i];
    if(number[i] > max){
        cout<<"\nHighest number is: "<<number[i];
    }
    else if (number[i] == number[i]){
        cout<<"\nDo not repeat the same number twice!";
        i=i-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's an eyesore as it is now.

Comment: @George It still shows the last input i have entered, not the highest number.

Comment: @JamesBong its not the only problem: `max = number[i] + 1` -> `max = 0` & `(number[i] == number[i])` -> `(i > -1 && (number[i-1] == number[i])` & `highest` is redundant & `i` is re declared.

Answer (score 0):

also take care that your `else if (number[i] == number[i])` will always fire because you are comparing the number with itselfe.

Comment: so that means `else if (number [i] == number[i+1])`?

Comment: @JamesBong Nope, that would yield undefined behaviour.

Comment: you need to compare the given number, which is number[i] with all numbers which have been entered previously.

Comment: How do i take the value of `number[0]` without putting the 0 inside the []

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors. Here is one way to write this.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Loop iterators
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int j = 0;

  // Data storage -- expecting only positive values.
  unsigned int number[5];
  unsigned int max = 0;  
  bool duplicate;

  // No incrementation here, as we want to skip invalid cases
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ) {
    duplicate = false;
    std::cout << "\nEnter number: ";
    std::cin >> number[i];

    // Check that we don't have the same number in twice
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      if(number[i] == number[j]) { 
        std::cout << "\nDo not repeat the same number twice!" << std::endl;
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }

    // If a duplicate has been found, skip the rest of the process.
    if (duplicate) {
      continue;
    }

    // Is this a new maximum?
    if (number[i] > max) {
      max = number[i];
    }
    ++i;
  }

  std::cout << "Highest number is : " << max << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am using turbo c compiler

Comment: Then you probably want to mark the question as turbo-c and not c++. Anyways, just replace the `#include <iostream>` with an `#include <iostream.h>` and remove the `std::`s. I suppose that should be enough.

Comment: @JamesBong: if you're not obliged to use turbo c, please find something else (VisualStudio Express, Eclipse CDT, QtCreator) . While clrscr() (and others) can be convenient, you still miss out on a lot of what more modern c++ has to offer. Also, don't just copy the code but try to understand what you did wrong and how it can be solved.

Comment: @stefaanv I am obliged to use turbo c. Yep i analyze the code before i try it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of `std::cin >>`: you could get invalid input (e.g. `if(! std::cin >> number[i]) { std::cout << "wrong input received"; return -1; }`)

initialize your max with the minimum value: `std::numeric_limits<int>::min();`  So the first number will always be the first max.  You should also update max when the input is higher.

if you only need to check the previous value, check that i is not zero (there is no previous value) and then check value[i] to value[i-1].  However, if you need all unique numbers then you should check all previous numbers in a loop.

Only do the output of the maximum value after the loop (inside the loop is only for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,number[5],highest,max = number[i] + 1;
```

because i just begin init then i = 0. number[i] realy number[0]. 
so max = number[0] + 1 = 1.
you must input all number to array:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"\nEnter number :";
    cin>>number[i];
}
```

after compare it:

```
max = number[i] + 1;  
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(number[i] > max){
        cout<<"\nHighest number is: "<<number[i];
    }

}
```